# How to rename shipping address field label in magento2

Tags: magento2, checkout, translate

I want to rename the shipping address field label as the First Name to Recipient First Name, Last Name as Recipient Last name and so on.

In Magento 2 I am not getting any clear document about this as I'm new to Magento plz guide me

Thanks in advance

Comment: Hey, Could you please provide more information. where do you need to rename field ? on the checkout page?

Comment: Yup..I want on checkout page..plz help me..im struggling from past 1week..

Comment: You can use translation dictionary to customize strings.

Comment: is translation dictionary a plugin????????

Answer (score 0, accepted):

there are multiple options to do this.

1) DB translation

Store -> Configuration -> Advanced -> Developer -> Translate Inline -> Enabled for Storefront set to Yes

2) You can do via theme transaction if you have made a custom theme as per your language.

i.e en_AU, en_US

After this do the following

php bin/magento deploy:mode:show

php bin/magento deploy:mode:set developer

Clear cache and static and deploy

sudo rm -R pub/static/*

sudo rm -rf var/cache/ var/generation/ var/page_cache/ var/view_preprocessed/

sudo php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy -f

Let me know if you have still any query than add me in skype : samumaretiya.

Thanks,
Sam

Comment: Hi i have tried all d above steps..but it dosent seems to work..

Comment: plz give me some other solutions..i hv added u on skype